# Laravel framework is clashing with SQL where-in

Tags: sql, laravel, where-in

Using Laravel framework. It look likes the Where-In sql query clashes with the framework. Am I wrong, and if not any work arounds?

```
    //terms is the search string sent to server. 
    //Am breaking it up into searchable tags.
    $terms = explode(" ", $term);

    $posts = DB::select('SELECT * FROM car
    WHERE model IN ?',
    implode(',',$terms));
```

Error:

```
prepareBindings() must be of the type array, string given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try 

`$posts = DB::select('SELECT * FROM car
    WHERE model IN (?)', [implode(',',$terms)]);`

and report back

I have updated the answer to reflect what worked for you.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 2 (SQL: SELECT * FROM car\n ◀
    WHERE model IN ford)

Comment: What ballocks. The following works.                                                
     $posts = DB::select('SELECT * FROM car
    WHERE model IN (?)', [implode(',',$terms)]);

Comment: why not DB::table('car')->whereIn('model', $array); ? or just DB::RAW ?